# Error installing ruby 1.9.3 on Snow Leopard

Tags: ruby, osx-snow-leopard, rvm

I tried installing ruby 1.9.3 on Snow Leopard using:

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
```

After installing the gcc compiler (I am running xcode 4.2). But I am getting the following make error:

```
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -dynamic -bundle -o ../../.ext/x86_64-darwin10.8.0/tcltklib.bundle stubs.o tcltklib.o -L. -L../.. -L/$
ld: in /usr/local/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib, missing required architecture x86_64 in file for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [../../.ext/x86_64-darwin10.8.0/tcltklib.bundle] Error 1
make: *** [mkmain.sh] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/usr/bin/gcc-4.2` is not provided in Xcode 4.2 this file might be left by older installation, try:

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
```

Also it could be solved by uninstalling Xcode with:

```
/Library/Developer/Shared/uninstall-devtools
rm -rf /Library/Developer/
```

And installing Xcode again (clean).

Comment: Redownloading xcode takes a bit of time...but will get back to you when this works!

Comment: Okay, I tried this (removing and re-installing xcode with instructions above) but got this error: The provided CC(/usr/bin/gcc) is LLVM based, it is not yet fully supported by ruby and gems, please read `rvm requirements`

Comment: I have removed setting CC from the answer, also make sure to really read output  of the `rvm requirements` command

Comment: I had a similar problem, but got a different error message (something about gcc and not supporting llvm), but your solution helped me, too. I just comment because I'm grateful =)